# Laravel 5.2 ServiceProvider override $listen array in own package

Tags: laravel-5, service-provider

What's the proper way to write the $listen mapping ?
- I got a package and a ServiceProvider file created in that package.

My problem is I don't know how to access the class path for the package, here is the code I tried:

```
/**
 * The event listener mappings for the application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $listen = [
  'damjan\random\ActionDone' => [
  'damjan\random\ThingToDoAfterEventWasFired',
  ],
];
```

Did I set the class path of the Listener and Event classes in a wrong scheme :) ?

Answer (score 1):

The `$listen` mapping is only used to register listeners at an app-level inside `App\Providers\EventServiceProvider`, not within a package's `ServiceProvider`.

The proper way to register an event listener from within a package's `ServiceProvier` in my opinion is to simply use the `Event` facade in it's `boot` function.

So in OP's case that would be:

```
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event::listen(
            'damjan\random\ActionDone',
            'damjan\random\ThingToDoAfterEventWasFired'
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same question a week ago. Found out today how to solve. I don't know if it's possible to overwrite the array but you could add a second service provider to your package with the same code as the Laravel 5.2 Event Service Provider.

Code can be found here: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php

Then you could serve this service provider within your package service provider with the following code:

```
/**
 * Register the service provider.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    $this->app->register(PackageEventServiceProvider::class);
}
```